# How to get class field type using Reflect only using constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code:

```
require('reflect-metadata');

function logType(target : any, key : string) {}

class Demo{ 
  @logType
  public attr1 : string = null;
}

console.log("test:");
var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", new Demo(), "attr1"); //LINE X
console.log(t.name);
```

This code works, however, I need to get the type of Demo.attr1 without creating instance of Demo, only using Demo constructor. Something like this

```
var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Demo, "attr1");
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metadata is registered on the `prototype` of the class. So you can pass in the prototype to get the metadata:

```
var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", Demo.prototype, "attr1"); 
console.log(t.name); // Object
```